# Android Sponsored link image broken

Tags: support, status-norepro, sponsored-tags

Image for the sponsored link part is broken (may be link is dead).

Here is the screenshot.
[image]

Comment: I can see it fine. What do you see when you go to: https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/pagead/imgad?id=CICAgKCr_PVqEAEYATIIeHLT-t1L8fE ?

Comment: that link shows the android logo but it doesn't show on that page that I have posted.

Comment: It is the same image - what happens when you refresh? What do you see in your browser console? What in the browser network tab (for that request)?

Comment: Are you using an ad blocker?

Comment: yes adblocker is the issue. This is what shown in the console. Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_ADBLOCKER

Comment: There you go then. You are blocking the image...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ad blocker software is blocking the image.

Not much we can do here...

Comment: I am not from web background but I want to ask then if I directly copy paste the link in the browser then it does show the image. Why so?

Comment: When I do that, the ad blocker I use doesn't show the image. You would need to ask the developers of your ad blocker software why that happens.

Comment: what I am saying is with ad blocker still enabled, when I open the image in new tab then it shows perfectly but not on that page.

Comment: And I am saying, you would need to ask the people who created your ad blocker why that is.